# Confused about numpy array operations

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How come this be right?

```
X=np.array([range(1,12)])     

A=X>4
B=X<10
C=(X>4) | (X<10)
print (X[A])
print (X[B])
print (X[C])



[ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
```

Comment: What's not clear? The first array is every element more than 4

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Comment: How's  variable C output right? I meant

Comment: Yes right... im dumb. Thanks

Comment: Because all elements are greater than 4 OR less than 10... Did you mean to use AND operator?

Comment: If the question is just about C, then you can edit your post to clarify

Comment: I tried to edit... And while saving there was a message that you already did it ...and something else...

Comment: @cricket_007 Still dont get it, you saying "What's not clear? The first array is every element more than 4" but the output is starting from  1 to 11 and shouldnt it be [ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11] or
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] if | means or..

Comment: The first array doesn't use C. You can't have a variable with two possible results, anyway

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess that your concern is because you have every element in the final expression, simply because the first two are obvious (`5..11` are all greater than four and `1..9` are all less than ten).

But the third one is *also* right since *every* element is either greater than four ***or*** less than ten. The numbers `1..9` are all less than ten so they're in. Similarly, `5..11` are all greater than four so they're in as well. The union of those two ranges is the entire set of values.

If you wanted the items that were between four ***and*** ten (exclusive at both ends), you should probably have used "and" instead of "or" (`&` instead of `|`):

```
import numpy as np
X=np.array([range(1,12)])     

A=X>4
B=X<10
C=(X>4) | (X<10)
D=(X>4) & (X<10)
E=(X<=4) | (X>=10)
print (X[A])
print (X[B])
print (X[C])
print (X[D])
print (X[E])
```

The output of that is:

```
[ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[5 6 7 8 9]
[ 1  2  3  4 10 11]
```

Because you didn't specify *what* you wanted in the original question), I've also added the opposite operation (to get values *not* in that range). That's indicated by the `E` code.

Comment: I thought that when C=(X>4) | (X<10) , one of the condition should be True.

Comment: @Cody, no its "one or the other, or both". You're thinking of exclusive or, XOR

Comment: @Cody, it's true if one or both are true (inclusive or). The operation for checking if only one is true is the exclusive or.

Comment: if i use & , that comes out [5 6 7 8 9]

Comment: That is indeed correct, @Cody. If that's not what you wanted, you probably should state clearly what it is you *did* want :-)

Comment: I thought right output at C would be either [ 5  6  7  8  9 10 11] or [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

Comment: @Cody: Ah, I see now. Unfortunately, that is a misunderstanding as to how it works. You may be better off thinking of it as a filter, with every element matching the expression being allowed through the filter. So, in the same way `X>4` gives you everything higher than four, `(X > 4) | (X < 10)` gives you everything that matches *that* expression, which is everything that matches one or both of the subexpressions, which (in this case) is everything. You could also consider `|` being set union if you wish, it'll have the same result.